# Is Slickgrid right-to-left compatible?

Tags: right-to-left, slickgrid

I am on Slickgrid v3.0.4. Is there any way to make the grid rtl compatible?

When I tried it, the column headers stopped working. Most headers turned invisible and when switching them around, the grid-columns were switched invertedly (When moving the leftmost header, the rightmost grid-column would be moved).
[image]

I already put the slickgrid css files through rtlcss, a tool that converts css files to make them rtl compatible.

Comment: the subject is already covered in this 6pac/slickgrid issue https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/issues/446 if that does not work for you then you will have to contribute to the project yourself since all maintainers use LTR only. Your question is also not really good for Stack Overflow since you did not provide any code

Comment: in addition to what @ghiscoding says (I am the other maintainer of the project), it would be handy if there are any problems to have a shared example file that demonstrates them. Start with an existing example file (you can run them locally direct from your repo), copy it and modity it. You can then use Git to create a PR with the new example file, or just create a GitHub issue and post the file as an attachment.

Comment: Thank you both for the feedback, I'm still experimenting. Does it still make sense to create a PR or an Issue if I'm on an old version of slickgrid?